# how to insert data in database which is populating from while loop

Tags: php, mysql

i have a condition here. i am fetching a data using while loop from database now i want to insert the same data in the different table

for example

```
|---------------------|

| id|name|rollno|class|
|1  |surj| 1234 |  10 |
-----------------------
|2  |pras| 1235 |  10 |
-----------------------
|3  |anuj| 1236 |  10 |
-----------------------
|4  |rete| 1231 |  10 |
-----------------------
```

now if i am inserting the same data in new table it is inserted like this

```
 | id|        name       |        rollno      |    class     |
 |1  |surj,pras,anuj,rete| 1234,1235,236,1231 |  10,10,10,10 |
```

i want to insert data in each row any help or any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop insted

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++) { 
        # code...
        $title=  mysql_escape_string($arr[$i]['title']);
        $link = $arr[$i]['link'];
        $str = "insert into story(title,link)values('$title','$link')" ;        
        $qry  = mysql_query($str) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: sorry for late reply but can you provide me a live example